# Exclude "README.md" from doxygen's "File documentation" list

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am struggling with the following problem. I use doxygen to document my C++ code, and use the `README.md` to document the main page of my code documentation, via

```
INPUT += README.md
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
```

in my doyxgen configuration file. Everything works, except that the file `README.md` appears in the "File documentation" section of my generated .pdf out of the `refman.tex` file (it doesn't appear in the "File list" section), like

```
8.24 /Users/username/qpp/README.md File Reference . . . . . . 123
```

This is extremely annoying, as I don't want this file to appear in any file list. Is there any way to remove it? I cannot just add it to the `EXCLUDE =` list, as if I do, it won't be used anymore to generate the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, I still haven't found an elegant solution. What you can do in case you don't want `README.md` to appear in the File Reference section inside your .pdf is to manually comment the line

```
%\input{_r_e_a_d_m_e_8md}
```

in the generated `refman.tex` file, and only after that compile the .tex file to produce the final .pdf

```
latexmk -pdf refman.tex
```

The issue does not appear in the `html` generated documentation, only in the `latex` one.

---

Another option is to add `.` to `STRIP_FROM_PATH` in `Doxyfile`

```
STRIP_FROM_PATH = .
```

Now, at least the full path will not appear anymore, so instead of something like

```
8.24 /Users/username/qpp/README.md File Reference . . . . . . 123
```

you'll only see

```
8.24 README.md File Reference . . . . . . 123
```